# Compares two strings in XYplorer 11.90 onwards

Tags: search

XYplorer is a tabbed file manager for Windows.  In the script menu  how do I  compared two strings  I couldn't find  information  from xplorer help?   was wondering if anyone  knows the commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

information taken from that xplorer help which can be accessed by pressing F1.

---

> compare()
>
> Compares two strings.
>
> Syntax
>
> compare(string1, string2, [method=b])
>
> method:
>
> b: [default] binary, bytes: strings are compared alphabetically
>
> i: same as b, but case-insensitive: A=a
>
> n: numeric: strings are converted to numbers (fractions use dot) and
>   then compared numerically
>
> v: version: compares file versions of formats like #.## or #.##.####
>   or #.##.##.##
>
> d: date: compares dates, optionally including times; both string1 and
>   string2 default to the current   date/time. Valid date syntax depends
>   on your locale.
>
> return:
>
> -1 if string1 < string2
>
> 0 if string1 == string2
>
> 1 if string1 > string2
>
> Examples
>
> echo compare("a", "b"); // -1
>
> echo compare("a", "A"); // 1 (a is sorted after A)
>
> echo compare("a", "A", "i"); // 0
>
> echo compare("2", "12", "b"); // 1
>
> echo compare("2", "12", "n"); // -1
>
> echo compare("10.20.0025", "7.60.0026", "b"); // -1
>
> echo compare("10.20.0025", "7.60.0026", "v"); // 1
>
> echo compare("24.08.2012", "25.08.2012", "d"); //-1
>
> echo compare("24.08.2012", "24.08.2012", "d"); //0
>
> echo compare("25.08.2012", "24.08.2012", "d"); //1
>
> echo compare("24.08.2012 08:43:01", "24.08.2012 08:43:02", "d"); //-1
>
> echo compare("24.08.2012 08:43:02", "24.08.2012 08:43:01", "d");

Find the latest version and information here. The site is updated frequently.

http://www.xyplorer.com/

User Forum

XYplorer User Forum:

http://www.xyplorer.com/xyfc/